# Why does the following JS boolean logic fail for everything other than where effectiveDateSelected = true and throughDateSelected = false

Tags: javascript

I am a complete novice at Javascript and having tried every possible combination of Boolean expressions I am left with the following code. Why does the following JS boolean logic fail for everything other than where effectiveDateSelected = true and throughDateSelected = false

```
            // initialisation  
            var effectiveDateSelected = new Boolean(false);
        var throughDateSelected = new Boolean(false);  

            // values read in from web page
            effectiveDateSelected = ...          
            throughDateSelected = ...

            // the logical expression 
        if ((effectiveDateSelected) && !(throughDateSelected)) {
            reportNum = 1;
            alert("1 reportNum=" + reportNum);
        }

        if (!(effectedDateSelected)  && (throughDateSelected)) { 
                            reportNum = 2;
            alert("2 reportNum=" + reportNum);
        }

        if (((effectedDateSelected)  && (throughDateSelected)) || 
            (!(effectedDateSelected)  && !(throughDateSelected))) {
            reportNum = 3;
            alert("3 reportNum=" + reportNum);
        }
```

Comment: What does "fail" mean? What would be the success? What is the code supposed to do?

Comment: btw, debug your code using the builtin browser console (F12 in chrome, firebug extension in firefox etc) and use console.log to print stuff instead of alert (that way you don't have to click OK every 2 seconds, and you can print things that are not strings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new Boolean()` is always truthy as it's an object, you want to use boolean primitives like `false` and `true` directly.

```
var condition = false;
```

You can see this when converting a boolean object to primitive:

```
Boolean( new Boolean( false ) ) //true
```

Comment: Thanks Esailija that explains it and provides a neat solution.